# Let $f$ be holomorphic such that $\overline{\sin(f(z))}$ is holomorphic. Show $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic.
I am trying to show that if $\overline{\sin(f(z))}$ is holomorphic, then $f$ is constant.

I think I need Cauchy Riemann equations but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Do you  mean $\overline{\sin(f(z))}$? MathJax/LaTeX commands start with a backslash, not with a forward slash.

Comment: *Hint:* Show first that if both $g(z)$ and $\overline{g(z)}$ are holomorphic then $g$ is constant.

Comment: @MartinR I am extremely confused as to why $g(z)$ and $\overline{g(z)}$ cannot both be holomorphic, assuming $g$ is a non-constant function. $\overline{g(z)}$ is just a reflection of the output of $g(z)$ about the real axis; why would it become non-differentiable?

Comment: @MartinR I proved your hint. And now sin(f(z)) is holomorphic because of the composition of holomorphic functions and $\overline{sin(f(z))} = sin(\overline{f(z)})$ so sin(f(z)) is constant. So f is constant?!

Comment: @IdioticShrike: As an example, $g(z) = \overline z$ is *not* complex differentiable.

Comment: @IdioticShrike it would still be real differentiable, but complex differentiability is much stronger, e.g  it implies preservation of orientation

Comment: @TorbenIsermann: I'd encourage you to add your efforts to the original question itself. (Your working until how you showed that $z \mapsto \sin(f(z))$ is constant.) After that, someone can add an answer as to how to conclude that $f$ is constant.